# Primefaces Datatable Filtering is Case Sensitive

Tags: jsf, primefaces

After I search for a string, it lists in datatable and I would like to know if I filter my string value in primefaces datatable in case insensitive, I'm using Primefaces 5.0 Community edition.

```
<p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{ProcessBean.kList}" emptyMessage="#{msg['noRecordsFound']}"
    dynamic="true" paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{user.ID}" 
    rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
    rowIndexVar="rowIndex" selectionMode="single" paginatorPosition="bottom">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{kisiProcessBean.onRowSelect}"
        update=":form:tabView" />

    <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="#{msg['searchResultsPanel']}"/>
    </f:facet>


    <p:column id="name" sortBy="#{user.name}" filterBy="#{user.name}" 
        styleClass="name">

            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.name)" value="#{msg['name']}" />

    </p:column>

    <p:column id="surname" sortBy="#{user.surname}" filterBy="#{user.surname}" styleClass="surname" >

            <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}" />
            <p:watermark for="@(.surname)" value="#{msg['surname']}" />

    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Fixed in a newer version. Check the issuelist, releasenotes, blog…

Comment: I updated Primefaces to 5.2 and problem solved thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in newer releases. Try one of those.